# Remove Part of Speech Tags after chunking

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, text-processing, pos-tagger, chunking

How to remove part of speech tags from the results of chunking ?
I am using NLTK to do this. Currently I can only iterate to the chunks using this code:

```
for i in sent_list:
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(i)

ChunkGram = r"""Chunk: {<VB.?>+<JJ.?>*<NN.?>}"""

ChunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(ChunkGram)
chunked = ChunkParser.parse(tagged)
for subtree in chunked.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'Chunk'):
    print(subtree)
```

lets say my results are as such:

```
(Chunk routing/VBG rework/NN build/NN)
(Chunk build/VBP instruction/NN schedule/NN lot/NN)
(Chunk based/VBN firm/NN plan/NN)
```

Expected Results:

```
'routing','rework','build'
```

OR

```
'routing rework build'
```

would it be possible to do so ? or else please advice me on what i can do to extract these phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this code which helped me to achieve the results i want.

```
for subtree in chunked.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'Verb'):
            verblist.append(" ".join([a for (a,b) in subtree.leaves()]))
```